# por que me sale el error "bad operand types for binary operator ´<"

Tags: java, bluej

Quiero hacer que haya un parametro para algun numero pero al poner el parametro en el codigo me salta el error ¿Que puede ser?

```
`public class Rango
{

        int numero;
        String conclucion;
        public String Rango(int numero)
 {
  this.numero = numero;

   if(0 < numero < 100)<============>AQUI ME SALE QUE ESTA EL ERROR
  {

}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que en la parte del condicional estás usando múltiples comparaciones, ahí es donde probablemente se encuentre su error, recuerde que existen varios operadores lógicos, entre los más básicos se encuentran:

1. Operador AND (condición **&&** condición2)
2. Operador OR (condición **||** condición2)

Por lo que, aplicando esto en tu código quedaría algo tal que :

```
        public class Rango {
    
    
            int numero;
            String conclucion;
            public String Rango(int numero)
     

      this.numero = numero;

       // Caso AND
    
       if(numero > 0 && numero < 100){
           //toDo
      
    }

     //Caso OR
       if(numero > 0 || numero < 100){ 
            //toDo

}

}
```

Saludos

Comment: Sí, es ese el problema. El OR no aplica a este caso porque `0 < numero || numero < 100` va a devolver siempre `true`.

Comment: @Mateo sí, tienes razón jeje